# gnuplot: how to change linetype for missing data?

Tags: gnuplot

By default gnuplot substitutes curve with straight line where data is missing. Is there a way to change linetype for this range? E.g. the whole curve is printed with continuous line while missing data substituted with dashed line?

Comment: I wonder if it possible without cycle / dividing data into blocks. But I think it is possible if one parsed the data to find all missing points, and changed linetype for the data nearby (hmm, three points including every missing value).

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to show the behavior you are asking about?  I almost understand what you are asking, but am not quite sure that I do.

Comment: thanks, lads. I have found my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Plot lines marking missing data with dashed lines.

```
set datafile missing "?"
set term wxt dashed
plot "1.txt" using ($1):($2) with lines title "line", "<grep -A1 -B1 '?' 1.txt" w lines lt 2 lc 1 title "missing"

:~$ cat 1.txt
1 2
2 3
3 9
4 ?
5 6
6 7
```

### Explanation:

Mark missing data as `?`.

`using ($1):($2)` makes missed data to be skipped (spaces in the plot).

Execution of `grep` selects a range of data including one line before `-A1` and one line after `-B1` every `?`, this is plotted with `dashed` lines (`lt 2`)

[image: The plot]

### *(UPD on comment)*

### Plot multiple columns marking missing data with dashed lines.

```
:~$ cat 1.txt
1 2 3
2 3 ?
3 9 5
4 ? 2
5 6 7
6 7 4
```

Change the last `gnuplot` command to:

```
plot for [i=1:2] "1.txt" using ($1):(column(i+1)) with lines lt 1 lc i title "line".i, for [i=1:2] "<awk -v u=$((".i."+1)) '{printf $1\" \";print $u}' 1.txt | grep -A1 -B1 '?'" using 1:2 w lines lt 2 lc i title "missing".i
```

[image: Multiple lines]

### Explanation:

`for [i=1:2]` is `gnuplot` iteration (cycle), made two times (file with three columns). Change `2` to your `column count - 1`.

The other thing to comment is `"<awk -v u=$((".i."+1)) '{printf $1\" \";print $u}' ..."`: here we enclose shell command in `""`, and concatenate string with `.`

 This is a way to pass gnuplot `i` variable to the shell executed - we concatenate a string with the first part of `awk` command with `i` and the second part of `awk` command.

We print to columns of file each time: the first - `printf $1`, and the `i+1`st (aka `u`'th, we pass it as argument to `awk`).
`\" \"` is just a space, double quotes should be escaped.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Is it possible to use pipe in that grep command? Because my datafile contains multiple columns. Each of them may have missed data.

Comment: Yes you can :) See UPD)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you wanted to pipe from `awk`!